# App Crashes when Requesting Permission to Use iPhone's Microphone with iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, avaudiosession, avaudiorecorder

My app crashes when I attempt to request permission to use the iPhone's microphone with the following code:

```
var permissionGranted = false
switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission() {
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
    setupRecorder()
    permissionGranted = true
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
    permissionGranted = false
case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission {
        [weak self] granted in
        if granted {
            self?.setupRecorder()
        }
    }
default:
    permissionGranted = false
    break
}
```

I also added `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to the app's Info.plist with a string. When I run the app, it crashes and Xcode prints an error message saying I need to add `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to the plist.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Update your question showing the relevant portion of your Info.plist verifying you have the correct entry for the permission.

Comment: Are you sure that your project's build settings is locating your info.plist correct path?

Comment: @MEnnabah I suspect you're right. I created a new project and added the existing code, and the app worked as expected.

Comment: Great, the check the file path in build settings

Answer (score 0):

Try using Below Function

```
 struct Manager {
    static var recordingSession: AVAudioSession!
    static var micAuthorised = Bool()        
}

func CheckForPermission()
    {
        Manager.recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do
        {
            try Manager.recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
//            try Manager.recordingSession.setPreferredSampleRate(16000)
//            try Manager.recordingSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
//            try Manager.recordingSession.setActive(true)
            Manager.recordingSession.requestRecordPermission({ (allowed) in
                if allowed
                {
                    Manager.micAuthorised = true
                    print("Mic Authorised")
                }
                else
                {
                    Manager.micAuthorised = false
                    print("Mic not Authorised")
                }
            })
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Failed to set Category", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```